# Google Analytics: Can you search and replace to capture URL segments?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, url-routing

I know that you can use Search and Replace regex filters to clean up your reports in google analytics.

search: `/?pageid=33` can become replaced with: `/sweaters`

however I want to use a regex filter, and capture part of URL similar how the [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) PHP function works. So:

search: `/ext/([a-z0-9]{32,})/(.*)` becomes replaced with: `/ext/($2)`

so my url of:

```
/ext/70ef47a47ae2ab929474ae65ddab0255/progress
```

is shown in GA as: `/ext/progress`

**Does anyone know if this is possible?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can indeed.

Just use an **Advanced Filter** and make sure that instead of ($2) you use `($A2)` or `($B2)` depending on if you use more than one custom filter